# Rails 4.1.6 Could not find generator bootstrap:install

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-rails

I am getting the message Could not find generator bootstrap:install on Rails 4.1.6

My gem file looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


 # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails'

gem 'rails', '4.1.6'

 # Use postgresql as the database for Active Record

gem 'pg'

 # Use SCSS for stylesheets

gem 'sass-rails'

 # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

 # Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

 # Use jquery as the JavaScript library

gem 'jquery-rails'

 # Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster.

gem 'turbolinks'

 # Build JSON APIs with ease.

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

 # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

 # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background.

gem 'spring',        group: :development

gem 'devise'

gem "therubyracer"

gem "less-rails"  #Sprockets (what Rails 3.1 uses for its asset pipeline) supports LESS

# twitter bootstrap css & javascript toolkit

gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'

# twitter bootstrap css & javascript toolkit

gem 'twitter-bootswatch-rails', '~> 3.2.0'

# twitter bootstrap helpers gem, e.g., alerts etc...

gem 'twitter-bootswatch-rails-helpers'
```

twitter-bootstrap-rails version is 3.2.0

therubyracer version is 0.12.1

execjs version is 2.2.2

When I run rails generate bootstrap:install less in command line, I get the above error. I do not understand what am I doing wrong.

Comment: first run `bundle install` and try the command

Comment: @anusha, I did that only, but got the above message.

Comment: what is `bootswatch-rails`

Comment: @anusha, you can ignore that for this issue as I tried after commenting bootswatch related gems, but still got the same message. Bootswatch gives themes based on bootstrap.